# Displaying Rich Text File in UITextView Causes Choppy/Slow Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitextview, rtf

Im currently loading a non-english (hebrew) Rich Text File into a UITextView like so.

```
self.textView.attributedText =
    [NSAttributedString.alloc
     initWithFileURL:[ NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"TextFile" withExtension:@"rtf"  ]
     options:nil
     documentAttributes:nil
     error:NULL
     ];
```

Everything get loaded correctly and the file scrolls, just it gets very choppy on the way down. I assume this is a rendering issue with UITextView.

Is there any other library or way to make the scrolling smooth.
Note: The UITextView is non-editable and non-selectable already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be ideal, but I've had this idea work in similar situations. Try increasing the height of the `UITextView`(to create a sort of buffer). You may have to adjust the `scrollIndicatorInsets`, `contentInsets`,  `layer.zPosition` of various `UIView`'s, and possibly make the `UITextView` transparent with another `UITextView` behind it with the proper size/border/etc depending on your layout.

**Option 2**

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 100, 200, 100)];
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.bounds.size.width, HEIGHT)];
label.text = @"text";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
[scrollView addSubview:label];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(label.bounds.size.width, label.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: Clever workaround but seems over complicated. But may be my only choice

Comment: maybe try a UILabel on a UIScrollView as an alternative. iOS frameworks have taught me the art of workarounds quite well. good luck.

Comment: Do I have to make the scroll view height and label height equal to the text length? If I use the UILabel+ScrollView approach?

Comment: The scrollview height should be the desired height of your previous textview and the label height should be enough to contain all the text. I'll update the answer.

Comment: UILabel + scroll view is working but takes a long time to render initially and changing font size with lots of text takes a while. Plus I need to search the text and scroll to that spot. All the stuff that is implemented in UITextView. There must be a way to speed up the UITextView. Possibly removing gestures.. Editable .. Selectable.. . I removed those but it's still slow/choppy